# Javascript click event not firing on element in user control in google chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, user-controls, attributes

I have a user control and an image within that and I wish to execute some javascript when it;s clicked, in the Page_Load event of my user control I add the following:

`imgCalendar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "displayDatePicker('" + txtCalendar.ClientID + "');");`

So I'm adding an `onclick` event to `imgCalendar` and I want that event to fill in my text box `txtCalendar` with the output of my Javascript function `displayDatePicker`, it works perfectly fine in Internet Explorer but the click event does not fire in chrome, any ideas on why this is? are there any other ways I can add that click attribute to my image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the name of the text box control was chaning when the HTML was renderd, so the function: `displayDatePicker('uc1_txtCalendar')` was getting called whereas the text box's name (note that it's *name* property **not ID** is used client side since an asp text box is rendered as a html input control) was rendered to 'uc111$textCalender', that '$' thrown in in place of the underscore was the problem, I resolved this [by giving everything a static ClientIDMode](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) (for the text box and it's container which in this case is the User Control)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this?

```
imgCalendar.addEventListener("click", "displayDatePicker('"+txtCalendar.ClientID+"')", false);
```

Comment: I've already tried attachEvent and addEventListener and it still doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome, this is a problem specific to controls inside ASP user controls (.ascx) as soon as I remove my user control the click event gets executed in every browser and it works like a charm.